# Extending the Bernoulli Equation to Rotation

Tags: energy, rotation, turbulence, bernoulli-equation

The standard Bernoulli Equation has three terms on each side, a kinetic energy term, a potential energy term and a pressure term.

I've never seen an extension of this to also include a rotational kinetic energy term.

Do things get too crazy when fluids rotate for a simple extension to the equation?

Comment: Here's one situation it'd be fun to be able to treat simply: When a tank has a hole in the bottom, is there a simple way to treat how the volume flow rate changes if there is a drain vortex?

Comment: Unfortunately, the tank with the drain vortex is not a simple problem anymore. If we represent the velocity field in a polar cylindrical coordinate system centered in the drain, with velocity components $v_r$, $v_\theta$ and $v_z$ ($z$-axis vertically down) then, sure, if we know the "rotational kinetic energy" $1/2 v_\theta^2$, and perhaps assuming that $v_r$ is small, we could get $v_z$ from a modified version of the Bernoulli equation. Trouble is, there's no simple way to find the "rotational part" ($v_\theta$). See Phys. Rev. Lett. (91) 10 for some inspiration...

Answer (score 2):

You can apply Bernoulli's equation to fluids that "rotate" in certain ways (for an irrotational fluid where fluid particles may still be subject to circular motion). Otherwise, in continuum mechanics for standard fluids, the particles described by the equations of motion carry no angular momentum or rotational energy, so there are no rotational kinetic energy terms. This is also the reason why, for example, the Navier-Stokes equation in terms of velocities and pressure is *equivalent* to the vorticity transport equation.